# Lua sample-fetch 'routeIP': runtime error: /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3: attempt to call a nil value (method 'fhdr') from /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua

Tags: lua, haproxy, distributed-system, system-design, x-forwarded-for

I was trying to print my 'X-forwarded-for' header using LUA script in HAProxy. But I am getting error

**/var/log/haproxy.log**

```
May 18 18:37:06 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 haproxy[161927]: [ALERT] 137/183706 (161927) : Lua sample-fetch 'routeIP': runtime error: /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3: attempt to call a nil value (method 'fhdr') from /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3 C function line 1.
May 18 18:37:07 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01 haproxy[161927]: [ALERT] 137/183707 (161927) : Lua sample-fetch 'routeIP': runtime error: /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3: attempt to call a nil value (method 'fhdr') from /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3 C function line 1.
 Lua sample-fetch 'routeIP': runtime error: /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3: attempt to call a nil value (method 'fhdr') from /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:3 C function line 1.
```

Here is my haproxy.cfg file, where I am setting the X-forwarded-for header.

```
#HAProxy for web servers
frontend web-frontend
  bind 10.122.0.2:80
  bind 139.59.75.106:80
  mode http

  http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } # For Proto
  http-request add-header X-Real-Ip %[src] # Custom header with src IP
  option forwardfor # X-forwarded-for

  use_backend %[lua.routeIP]
```

The Lua script where I am printing the same `route_req.lua`

```
local function getIP(txn)
        local clientip = txn.f:src()
        local src = txn.f:fhdr("x-forwarded-for");

        core.log(core.info, "ClientP and XForwardedFor header : " .. clientip .. " - " .. src)
        // My code goes here

end

core.register_fetches('routeIP', getIP)
```

Where exactly I am going wrong why isn't the X-forwarded-for header set?

As I understand this field contains the IP address of the last device as well which forwarded my request, so I can't use just the src.

Provides a list of connection IP addresses.

> The load balancer appends the last remote peer address to the
> X-Forwarded-For field from the incoming request. A comma and space
> precede the appended address. If the client request header does not
> include an X-Forwarded-For field, this value is equal to the X-Real-IP
> value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that `txn.f` doesn't contain a method called `fhdr`. Maybe you meant `req_fhdr` instead.

Comment: I tried with req_fhdr, didn't work

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar What does "didn't work" mean? What happened exactly?

Comment: It means that I am still getting same error `Lua sample-fetch 'routeIP': runtime error: /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:5: attempt to concatenate a nil value (local 'src') from /etc/haproxy/route_req.lua:5 C function line 1.
`

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar That's a different error, so that means this *did* work. Your new problem is you're not correctly handling the case when the header wasn't set.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why is this header not set when I am clearly using the `option forwardfor`